# How to define a custom event callback function argument shape in a class with typescript?

Tags: typescript, class, interface, callback

```
import EventEmitter from 'events';

type Bar = {
  just: string;
  test: number;
};
class Foo extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addListener('my_event', (bar: Bar) => {
      console.log(bar);
    });
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();

foo.emit('my_event', {
  /* The question is: */
  /* How to tip the argument key when I enter the `ctrl+space` keyboard ? */
});
```

I don't know how to define the callback argument shape, then the vscode can tip me the event argument key when I enter the `ctrl&space` keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this example:

```js
import EventEmitter from 'events';

type EventMap = {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
};

class CustomEvents extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.addListener('bar', (bar) => {
            // bar is a number
            console.log(bar);
        });
    }

    addListener<Name extends keyof EventMap>(event: Name, cb: (args: EventMap[Name]) => void) {
        this.addListener(event, cb)
        return this
    }

    emit<Name extends keyof EventMap>(event: Name, payload: EventMap[Name]) {
        this.emit(event, payload)
        return true
    }
}

const foo = new CustomEvents();
foo.addListener('bar', (arg) => {
    arg.toExponential() // ok, because arg is number
})

foo.addListener('bar', (arg: string) => {
    arg.toExponential() // expected error, because arg should be a number
})

foo.emit('bar', 'string') // expected error because payload sjould be a number
```

[enter link description here](https://tsplay.dev/mq3qZw)

you need to create your own methods `addListener` and `emit` with appropriate validation. Also, please keep in mind that you need an event map type, where each KEY is an event name and property is an event payload.

You can check my [article](https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe) about typing publish/subscribe pattern

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want.

I think it would be better to use `super` replaced with`this` in the`emit` and`addListener` function.